# Change date string with "am/pm" to actual date in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I have a column of dates written as strings with "am" and "pm" at the end, for example:

```
1/1/2016 12:00:00.000 AM
```

The type of the column is currently `varchar`, I want to change the type to `datetime` format.

**Attempt 1**

Changing the column type from phpmyadmin dashboard gives the following error:

```
Query error:
#1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '1/1/2016 12:00:00.000 AM'
```

**Attempt 2**

Considering the format of the date, I tried to use the STR_TO_DATE function. But it does not give the expected result. It instead returns the same date for each row.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(`assembling-machine-tag`.`Time`, "%Y") from `assembling-machine-tag`
```

**Result**

[image]

So, how can I change the format of my column from `varchar` (with format = `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss.ms AM`) to `datetime` (with format = `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`) in MySQL 7.4.1?

Comment: str_to_date() function is the one you need, you just need to use the right format string. Mysql manual has a comprehensive documentation of the format strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use the [correct pattern](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format):

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1/2/2016 01:02:03.456 AM', '%e/%c/%Y %h:%i:%s.%f %p')
-- 2016-02-01 01:02:03.456000
```

In order to convert varchar data to datetime, you first need to create a temporary `datetime` column and update it like so:

```sql
UPDATE t SET `datetimetemp` = STR_TO_DATE(`varchardate`, '%c/%e/%Y %h:%i:%s.%f %p')
```

Once satisfied with result drop, the varchar column and rename the temporary column.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this version:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('1/1/2016 12:00:00.000 PM', '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i:%s.%f %p')
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there is no such thing as 12 AM (as in ops example) so there may be a fix required to data first.